# Could not show content in CKeditor after the second time

Tags: ckeditor, init, destroy

In my project, the Ckeditor is part of a webpage, which is coded using GWT. So the interface to CKeditor is using Java.

Whenever the webpage is displayed, the CKeditor will be passed a HTML via `setData()`, which the CKeditor is supposed to show.

The problem is: CKeditor sometimes won't show the HTML. Its content was just empty, although I am very sure the html had been passed to `setData()`.

I had tried several approaches to solve this problem, but none would work.

### My approach

- Create a `TextArea` using `DOM.createTextArea()`
- Call `myEditor=CKEDITOR.replace(textArea, config)` to initialize the CKeditor
- call `myEditor.setData(html)` to set the content.

It was good and showed the content at the first time.

But after the webpage got hidden and shown again, I called `myEditor.setData(html2)` to show another html, but this time the CKeditor showed nothing.

### First solution  (did not work)

I changed the code to call `myEditor.destroy()` before the webpage was hidden, and call `CKEDITOR.replace(textArea, config)` again when the webpage was visible again, after that I called `myEditor.setData(newHtml)`.

This time it worked in IE and FF, but not in Chrome and Edge, it kept showing the content of the first load time, instead of showing the new HTML.

### Second solution (did not work)

I changed it to call `CKEDITOR.inline(textArea, config)` instead of `CKEDITOR.replace(textArea, config)` when the webpage was visible again, while the `destroy()` and `setData()` was still called in the same order. This time the CKeditor again didn't show anything from the second time.

## Last attempt

My last approach was to not calling `destroy()`, but creating a new `TextArea` each time before showing CKeditor, and called `CKEDITOR.replace(textArea, config)` and `setData(html)`. This seems to work well, but occasionally the CKeditor still showed empty content.

Could anyone please help me to solve this problem?

I am using CKeditor 4.5.8.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured out the solution:

Before hiding the ckeditor, call editor.destroy(true), and delete editor. (Before this, I only called editor.destroy() [note: no 'true'], which didn't work well).

Here is the code:

```
    if (editor) {
        editor.destroy(true);
        delete editor;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this java script code that is very simple and effective.Note editor1 is my textarea id

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    CKEDITOR.timestamp= new Date();
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
  });
</script>
```

second way ! In controller ,when your query is fetch data from database then use this code after .success(function().

```
 $http.get(url).success(function(){
   CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
});
```